# Keep the file open, don't lose data when the app crashes

Tags: c#, filestream

I need to log info to a file around 1000-2000 times a minute. I also need to save that info in case the app crashes.

Currently here's what I'm doing:

```
using(StreamWriter sw=new StreamWriter(filename,true))
{
    sw.WriteLine(info);
}
```

This works, but it's extremely slow.

I'd like to be doing something like this:

```
static StreamWriter sw=new StreamWriter(file,true);

....

public static void Main(...)
{
    .....
    sw.WriteLine(....);
}
```

but when I write code like this, I'm afraid that the info I store will get lost when the app crashes.

What can I do to preserve info in the file without having to open and close it all the time?

Comment: use [log4net](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140911/log4net-Tutorial)

Answer (score 6):

You can call [`StreamWriter.Flush()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.flush.aspx) after each write.

```
public static void Main(...)
{
    .....
    sw.WriteLine(....);
    sw.Flush();
}
```

But you should use [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/) or [Log4Net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/)!

Comment: Does either of those logging frameworks have the ability to efficiently log things "tenetatively" and have such entries "evaporate" if an operation completes successfully, but still get written if the operation fails?

Comment: @supercat Not as far as I know.

Comment: Curious.  I've been thinking of writing my own logging framework, with that as one of the primary features, but was deterred by the mantra of "don't roll your own logging framework".  In many cases, if e.g. an operation with a remote server succeeds nothing would be gained by having logged the details of everything sent to and received from it, but if an operation fails even information which would normally be worthless might turn out to be extremely valuable.  Being able to have logging verbosity depend upon whether an operation succeeds or fails would seem very commonly useful.

Comment: @supercat I guess most people just go for the `if (operationFailed) Log.Report("something")` approach.

Comment: In some cases that's fine; the difficulty arises in cases where things go "slightly" wrong but are not immediately detected.  To use an analogy, I saw a show where a beer company hired a company to set up high speed cameras on its line which continuously recorded 5000 frames/second into buffers for the purpose of determining why, about once a day, beer cans would start flying all over the place.  The cameras were allowed to run until the line "crashed", whereupon they were examined to see what had been happening in the 30 seconds or so before the crash.

Comment: Equipment to store 5000 frames/second for hours on end would be horrendously expensive, but the video from most of the time that the line was working perfectly would have been worthless even if it was retained.  The video of the last 30 seconds, however, proved invaluable since it made it possible to see how a few cans got very slightly nicked at one point in the line, and occasionally such a can would rotate so that the nick would hit a slight projection on the line which would dent it further.  If the larger dent hit a third spot, the can would snag just long enough to send the next can...

Comment: ...on an errant course which would then trigger a massive calamity.  Likewise if software is either multi-threaded or involves multiple devices communicating, it's possible for subtle things to go wrong in ways that don't normally cause trouble.  If X sends information to Z via Y, but when Z is asked for the information it doesn't have it, knowing whether Y received the information, and whether Y sent it before Z was asked for it, can be very helpful even though logs of everything sent and received would normally not be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I've used this [class](http://www.bondigeek.com/blog/2011/09/08/a-simple-c-thread-safe-logging-class/) it implements a queue that is flushed every X message or Y time.

You can improved it moving the using block outside the while in flushLog() and setting a fixed filename